# Is it safe to call jQuery ajax every 1 second

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have php file, that generates json with a countdown seconds to the New Year eve and to some birthdays. But I want the countdown to change every one second. Is it safe (will it overload the server) if I setTimeout(1000) to my ajax call function?
And what's the best way to implement 1 second JSON call via jQuery?
Thank you

Comment: why would you need ajax for that?

Comment: Whether it will overload the server is dependent on your server. What's stumping me even more is why you need to use php at all? Just do it in javascript.

Comment: @A.Wolff As he mention: _...and to some birthdays_ He might get birthday details from db.

Comment: @asku Still, why do you need ajax? Load all the birthdays into JSON on page load.

Comment: @aksu Why can't the birthdays be written to the page during the intitial page load and use javascript still?

Comment: @aksu So what? It could be done in JS only, with dates printed by php

Comment: @aksu and still don't explain why OP need ajax for that

Comment: There's still no need to use Ajax for that. Just provide a day's worth of data (or more if you expect the page to be displayed for a long period, you can use Ajax to update it daily if you like) and then use the system clock for the timer.

Comment: you can do a HEAD request to have timestamp of the server and use it to calculate via JS the time remaining from now to  the date.

Comment: It doesn't use jQuery, but facebook does something similar with how it updates it's pages, and it's returning quite a bit of data. However, that said, facebook has a huge amount of data processing resources available to it. That said, I think it depends on your back end, and infrastructure, and how much data you grab at once. Try to avoid multiple connections as much as possible and make just one request every so often if you can manage

Comment: Yea, i just note you about it...

Comment: Safe? yes, until you reach the maximum capability of your server. Is it a good idea? no, primarily because the timer will be off/inconsistent and it's far more network traffic than you need to accomplish this goal.

Comment: Network latency will cause it to lose time...

Answer (score 5):

Instead of overloading your server with requests (take into context you might have many users doing many requests at once coupled to your constants callbacks), take your data all at once for the following day for example and process the birthdays only in javascript.

The only Ajax portion i'd use in there would be to load more birthdays once per hour or day in case you have a really hyped user that leave his browser open.

Answer (score 2):

The load on the server depends on:

1. The amount of work the php does each time it is called
   and
2. The number of users you expect

Depending on what the server is doing, you may well be able to move the countdown logic into the client javascript, with the server just calculating the initial values. You can then use a timer in javascript to update every second, calculating the difference between the current time and the starting values.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your server and how optimised your PHP endpoint is... its a very conditional question.

However for what your doing, I would also suggest doing it all from JS.. even with birthdays, I would set a JSON object in the markup with all the birthdays that are recorded, then you can do it all client side... maybe call ajax every 5-10 minutes for any new birthdays that may be added... depends on what your application is.

Answer (score 1):

I used setInterval, and checked if the remaining time equals zero. Then I rerun the ajax function.

thank you, all :) you were helpful after all ;)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand, you want to call your server every second to update your time.

Can't you just :

1. Call your server to get the actual time
2. List item 2 - Process with a JS `setInterval(functionIncrementAndUpdateDate, 1000);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Keith Wood's countdown timer: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

It is extremely easy to use and no need for AJAX. All you have to do is include the plugin file and write:

```
<div id="timer"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#timer').countdown({
        until: '<?php echo date("h:i:s"); ?>' // change this to New Year or a Birthday from DB
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tqyj4/436/